# Multi-Language and Resource Files

Tags: vb.net, resx, multilingual

I have a question about creating a multi-language application and the use of resource files. I will explain what I have done and what I would like the final product to be like.

I am doing this in VB.Net and using Visual Studio 2008

After creating a new project, I added a resource file to the project (Add -> New Item, Selected Resource File, named it Resource1.resx).

I then double clicked the resource file and was able to add some names and values. For example,

Name – lblFirstName, value – John
Name – lblLastName, value – Smith

On my form, I have 2 labels: FirstName, and LastName

In Code, I added

```
FirstName.Text = My.Resources.Resource1.lblFirstName
LastName.Text = My.Resources.Resource1.lblLastName
```

If I run this code, it works fine. John and Smith are displayed  on the labels.

Now for my question. Say instead of first and last name the labels (buttons, menu items, etc.) were actually words that would be different in different languages. What I would like is to have something like

EnglishText.resx
SpanishText.resx
GermanText.resx

Each resource file would contain the same names, just different values. Depending on what language was selected, decided by the user (from a menu), how can I get the matching resource file to be used.

Basically what I want would be

```
FirstName.Text = My.Resources.<Language Specific Resource File>.lblFirstName
```

Is something like this possible? Is this an acceptable approach? Is there a better way of doing this?

Any tips or advice would be greatly appreciated. I try to check often to see if there are follow up questions or if more information needs to be provided.

Answer (score 2):

The .NET platform is built with localization in mind.  There is already an inborn mechanism for localizing assemblies and resources based on the current culture.  Here are some starter links you should read before trying to roll your own:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398937.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688096.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Resources

Public Class Form1
    Public rm As Resources.ResourceManager

    Private Property CultureInfo As CultureInfo
    Public Function getRMValue(ByVal strValue As String)
        Dim strLanguage As String

        If IsNothing(rm) Then
            strLanguage = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.ToString.ToUpper.Substring(0, 2)
            If strLanguage = "EN" Then
                rm = My.Resources.English.ResourceManager
            Else
                rm = My.Resources.Turkce.ResourceManager
            End If
        End If
        getRMValue = rm.GetString(strValue)
    End Function
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnBye_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBye.Click
        MessageBox.Show(getRMValue("messagebox"))

    End Sub
End Class
```

[Resource screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g268G.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Typically answers will be better received if you include a brief description, even for simple answers.

Comment: @joel Thank you. This would probably a nice answer since this is the "most" detailed. Unfortunately I dont know how to proceed from here and how to use the resource data and thus this answer is mostly useless. So my appeal to ahmet, please update your answer so it is a bit more clear what is happening and how to proceed from here, if you want to help.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say, you have 3 languages you could do something like this:

```
If LanguageChanger<change this to the way you let people change languages> = "English" Then
Language = My.Resources.EnglishText 
else if LanguageChanger = "Spanish" Then 
Language = My.Resources.SpanishText
else if LanguageChanger = "German" Then 
Language = My.Resources.GermanText
End if
```

You could then use it by:

```
FirstName.Text = Language.lblFirstName
```

I've just done this from within this form, it's not tested so sorry if it doesn't work